# how to call the python function by passing the output of the function as input to the function

Tags: python, function, input, output, call

I need to write a python function call logic that calls the python function multiple times.

let's say for example I have a script `test.py`

I'm running the script like `python test.py val`

```
val=sys.argv[1]
def check(param, val):
    .
    .
    .
    if val == valid.text:
        print '{:10s}:{:10}'.format(param, all.text)

values=os.walk(runtime).next()[1]
for param in values:
    check(param, val)
```

so here the output like

```
driver                          1.1
dmname                          1.5-temp
fdrmenu                         1.0-rem
```

so here I need to run the same function `check(param, val)` by taking the output as input for the function call.

the function calls like check(param, val) --> here val should be `driver` and so on for `dmname` , `fdrmenu`.

and call same function for output of `driver`, `dmname` and so on until we get the null for all the outputs.

here `sys.srgv[1]` should assign to val only for the first time, from next time it should be `driver`, `dmname` and so on.

Comment: How about `for val in ('driver', 'dmname', 'fdrmenu'):` instead of using `sys.argv`?

Comment: Put `values=os.walk(runtime).next()[1]` inside the for loop will accomplish this ?

Comment: @Klaus D - ```'driver', 'dmname', 'fdrmenu'```. These are not static the output will change every time. we can not hardcode the output

Comment: @ Nihal Sangeeth  - we should not put ```values=os.walk(runtime).next()[1]``` inside the for loop

Comment: @dubru Perhaps a bit more clarity on the question might help us.

Answer (score 0):

Something recursively like this?

```
data={'driver':'1.1','dmname':'1.5-temp','fdrmenu':'1.0-rem'} 
def check(data,key):
    val = data.pop(key)
    if type(val) == str:
        print(key,val)
        if data: check(data,list(data.keys())[0])
    return None

check(data,list(data.keys())[0])
```

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly so I don't know if I'm on the right track.

This function basically takes a dictionary (data) of elements of key/value pairs and you call it with the dictionary and its first key.

```
check(data,list(data.keys())[0])
```

Inside the function you extract the value associated to the key and delete the pair

```
val = data.pop(key)
```

So the dictionary started like

```
{'driver':'1.1','dmname':'1.5-temp','fdrmenu':'1.0-rem'}
```

the first key is 'driver' and the value is '1.1'. So now the variable val == '1.1' but the dictionary is now

```
{'dmname':'1.5-temp','fdrmenu':'1.0-rem'}
```

because the first key/value pair was deleted with the pop function

Then using the val you extracted you check a condition

```
if type(val) == str:
```

in this case val == '1.1' so it checks and then you print the key and the value which are 'driver' and '1.1'

then you check that the dictionary is not None and if it isn't you call the same function in the same way as before but since you deleted the first key/value pair from the dictionary the next first key/value element will be 'dmname':'1.5-temp'

```
{'dmname':'1.5-temp','fdrmenu':'1.0-rem'}
```

The next call the dictionary will be just one element

```
{'fdrmenu':'1.0-rem'}
```

and the last call the dictionary will be empty

```
{}
```

so the condition

```
if data
```

will not check and the function will return None

You could do something like this with pairs of params and values in your case if I understand your question correctly.

I modified the function to use the type of data you apparently have so the output of this function will be

```
driver 1.1
dmname 1.5-temp
fdrmenu 1.0-rem
```